# Unable to access Software Center - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: software-center

I am unable to access Software Center. I have tried to remove and reinstall it, but its failing with the below errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove software-center

dpkg: error processing package software-center (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-center
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
dpkg: error processing package software-center (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-center
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you manually removed some files installed by the `software-center` package. You need to re-install it.

Run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Comment: And do not manually remove system files in the future. It is not always that easy to recover.